# Dynamically assign column index in apex:dataTable with apex:repeat

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

Here is what I'm trying to achieve.

```
<apex:variable value="{!0}" var="colNum" />
<apex:dataTable ...>
    <apex:column>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:repeat ...>
        <apex:column>
            <apex:variable var="colNum" value="{!colNum + 1}" />
            <apex:facet name="header">
                <apex:outputPanel>
                    // here I have an element, I want to assign column number
                    // to that element. I tried using apex:variable, but is not 
                    // helping or may be I didn't do it the right.
                    <select id="{!colNum}"></select>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:facet>
        </apex:column>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:dataTable>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding some non-numeric character at the start of the ID, e.g. `<select id="select{!colNum}" />`. See if that works

Comment: @Bachovski That didn't work.

Comment: What is the result that you're getting? Is it always "0"?

Comment: I was able to solve by moving the increment tag inside the apex:facet.